# How can i pass a va_list through a function in C90

Tags: c, variadic-functions, c89, cvi

I want to pass a va_list through to another function. Here is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
void my_printf_1(char* string, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, string);
    printf(string, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

void my_printf_2(char* string, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, string);
    printf(string, *ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(void) {
    my_printf_1("Hello %i\n", 12); //Shows me the pointer
    my_printf_1("Hello \n"); //Runtime Error - too many arguments
    my_printf_2("Hello %i\n", 12); //Displays correctly because 12 < char
    my_printf_2("Hello %i\n", 500); //Displays incorrectly  because 500 > char
    my_printf_2("Hello %i %i\n", 12, 12); //Displays 12, then crashes Runtime Error not enough arguments
    my_printf_2("Hello \n"); //Runtime Error - too Many Arguments
}
```

It seems to me that my `va_list ap` is a `char` pointer, how can i get the whole List? How can i rewrite `my_printf()` to pass the whole or a fake `va_list` to subfunctions? I can not modify my subfunctions to accept `va_list` pointers, so i will have to modify `my_printf`.

EDIT:
I realize that the following would work, however this is not what i want.

```
void my_printf_1(char* string, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, string);
    vprintf(string, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: Your compiler+headers may happen to define `va_list` as `char*`, but that is implementation dependent. You can only operate on a `va_list` with `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_copy` and `va_end`, as described in e.g. C99 standard 7.15.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do what you say, but explicitly. That is, pass the actual `va_list` object.

See the `vsnprintf()` function for inspiration. Functions that take an explicit `va_list` are often prefixed with a `v` in the standard library.

The `va_list` doesn't have an internal structure that you can work with, it's opaque. All you can do is defined in the `<stdarg.h>` header.

Comment: i should have been more explicit, i basically want to mock a real va_list.

Comment: Aside from this, it is not possible. You cannot pass the arguments onto another variadic function with C.

Comment: Can i create a fake one and cast it into the right format? E.g. via an array or a struct?

Comment: `va_list` is not opaque: it's even documented in the SystemV ABI and it's not opaque because you can change the fields. I did it here: https://gitlab.com/eric.saintetienne/revstr#using-vsscanf It's not portable of course as with anything ABI related.

Answer (score 1):

Check out vprintf and friends. http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/vprintf/